# R Fit linear line or exponential curve through peaks and lows of timeseries

Tags: r, plot, line

I would like to plot a linear or log line through the peaks and lows in a times series with decreased peaks and lows like in the images. How do I do that?

In oher words: a line with its origin at the data series' peak, with the most negative slope possible, that doesn't intersect the data series at any other point. Which also accounts for the lows. Preferably both a lineair line as an exponential line.

The red lines I had drawn manually cause I dont know how to get them via R, hence thats the goal of the question. The following code gives the timeseries.

```
set.seed(123)

# Generate time series 
n <- 10000
x <- cumsum(rnorm(n, 0, 1))
sigma <- seq(2, 0.1, length.out = n)
x <- x * sigma

# Plot the time series
plot(x, type = "l")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you define the points through which the line will run?  For example, in the first plot, the line appears to fit the highest peak, but also seems to fit one on the right side of the plot.  However, the one on the right side of the plot isn't the second highest point, for example.  How would you identify that point in a general way?

Comment: Thats indeed a question I still didnt resolve.....so basically it needs to be a line where all the peaks (and lows) should fall into....so it needs to calaclulate and check wether thats the case and based on that draw the line....so as the time series progress and possibly a higher peak arises at the end..the line should move up than too

Comment: I think I would phrase it, e.g. for the top line, as: a line with its origin at the data series' peak, with the most negative slope possible, that doesn't intersect the data series at any other point.

Comment: There are a few R libraries which will identify local peaks for you.  I'd recommend that you first run a smoothing algo ( loess or  spline) to get rid of the "noise."  Then find the peaks, extract from the dataset, and fit them to whatever curve you like.

Comment: I added to the function to allow the x-variable to be logged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) max/min slope** Determine the maximum slope between the maximum and points to the right of the maximum and the minimum slope from the minimum to points to the right of the minimum.

```
plot(x, type = "l")
n <- length(x)

w.mn <- which.min(x)
x1 <- x[w.mn:n]
m1 <- min((x1[-1] - min(x1)) / ((w.mn+1):n - (w.mn)))
segments(w.mn, min(x), n, min(x) + m1 * (n - w.mn), col = "red", lwd = 2)

w.mx <- which.max(x)
x2 <- x[w.mx:n]
m2 <- max((x2[-1] - max(x2)) / ((w.mx+1):n - (w.mx)))
segments(w.mx, max(x), n, max(x) + m2 * (n - w.mx), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) quantile regression**.  Another way to do this is to use quantile regression.  We show the lines in red and the log upper curve in green.  The lower curve does not really make sense for log due to negative values in `x`.

```
library(quantreg)

xx <- seq_along(x)
plot(x ~ xx, type = "l")

fm <- rq(x ~ xx, tau = 0:1)
yy <- predict(fm)
lines(yy[, 1] ~ xx, col = "red", lwd = 2)
lines(yy[, 2] ~ xx, col = "red", lwd = 2)

fm.log <- rq(log(x) ~ xx, tau = 1)
yy.log <- cbind(1, xx) %*% coef(fm.log)
lines(exp(yy.log) ~ xx, col = "green", lwd = 2)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thx! So how would that work if I want to draw a more logarithmic line like in my last example? So the line is closer to the middle peaks?

Comment: See solution (2).

Comment: Thx! IfI add the same number to all x the plot becomes fully positive (e.g. `x <- x+20)`....however the lower expponential curve is bended than the wrong way if I use `fm.log <- rq(log(x) ~ xx, tau = 0)`...so with a cooeficient bending the curve towards the x-axis....Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Try  negating it and then taking log without the shift. `plot(x, type = "l");
fm.log <- rq(log(-x) ~ xx, tau = 1);
yy.log <- cbind(1, xx) %*% coef(fm.log);
lines(-exp(yy.log) ~ xx, col = "green", lwd = 2)`

Comment: Btw In `log(-x) : NaNs produced` does this matters? The line is correct btw. Thx for all your help btw!

Comment: Either just leave it or to remove the warning in (2) replace the `fm.log<- ...` line with `fm.log <- rq(log(abs(x)) ~ xx, subset = x > 0, tau = 1)`

Comment: Ah I indeed ignored it...one question: I do get an error like `Error in rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau, ...) : Singular design matrix` with the following data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7c8euot105otpm/DF.csv?dl=0
How come? I already searched a bit but am a bit confused

Comment: There are no negatives in that data so the original  code which depended on that won't be appropriate.  Also note NA in `DF$x`. Use `x <- na.omit(DF$x);
xx <- seq_along(x);
plot(x ~ xx, type = "l");
fm.log <- rq(log(x) ~ xx, tau = 0);
yy.log <- predict(fm.log);
lines(exp(yy.log) ~ xx, col = "green", lwd = 2);
fm.log <- rq(log(x) ~ xx, tau = 1);
yy.log <- predict(fm.log);
lines(exp(yy.log) ~ xx, col = "green", lwd = 2)`  .  Also just in case be sure you are using quantreg 5.95 which just appeared on CRAN.  Use the Switzerland mirror since it may not have propagated to the others yet.

Comment: Ah right ofcourse thx again!...however when have this data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7c8euot105otpm/DF.csv?dl=0 with positive and negative values...the log-lines match the tops and bottoms better, see: https://ibb.co/Swp59LG then when these values are all positive (so do x+5 for example) or negative (x-5)...when they are all positive the coefficient of the lines matched the data less better see https://ibb.co/17PZLKh. And when all negative the slope even looks counter-intuitive..see https://ibb.co/r0w5PBD

Comment: Ofcourse I can just add up a value so the data becomes positve and negative and get good slopes..but Im always curious why things dont work ;)

Answer (score 3):

Based on @zephyrl's suggestion, you could do a grid search over the slopes that have a starting point at the peak (or valley).  The stopping criterion would be intersection of any point in the series.  Here's a function that would do it.  The `series` argument is the series of data points, the `time` argument is for times associated with those series (to make the plot, `step` is the increment by which the slope is changed in each iteration and `log` is logical indicating whether the time variable should be logged.

```r
set.seed(123)

# Generate time series 
n <- 10000
x <- cumsum(rnorm(n, 0, 1))
sigma <- seq(2, 0.1, length.out = n)
x <- x * sigma
```

```r
find_lines <- function(series, time=NULL, step=1e-5, tol=1e-4, log=FALSE, ...){
  if(is.null(time)){
    time <- seq_along(series)
  }
  tmp <- data.frame(time = time, x=x)
  mx_tmp <- tmp[which.max(tmp$x), ]
  mx_tmp$x <- mx_tmp$x + tol
  mn_tmp <- tmp[which.min(tmp$x), ]
  mn_tmp$x <- mn_tmp$x - tol
  b_top <- 0
  b_bot <- 0
  if(!log){
    a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*mx_tmp$time 
    a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*mn_tmp$time 
    intersect_top <- any(tmp$x > b_top*tmp$time + a_top)    
    intersect_bot <- any(tmp$x < b_bot*tmp$time + a_bot)    
    while(!intersect_top){
      b_top <- b_top - step    
      a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*mx_tmp$time 
      intersect_top <- any(tmp$x > b_top*tmp$time + a_top)    
    }  
    b_top <- b_top + step
    a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*mx_tmp$time 
    while(!intersect_bot){
      b_bot <- b_bot + step    
      a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*mn_tmp$time 
      intersect_bot <- any(tmp$x < b_bot*tmp$time + a_bot)    
    }  
    b_bot <- b_bot - step
    a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*mn_tmp$time 
  }else{
    a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*log(mx_tmp$time)
    a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*mn_tmp$time 
    intersect_top <- any(tmp$x > b_top*log(tmp$time) + a_top)    
    intersect_bot <- any(tmp$x < b_bot*log(tmp$time) + a_bot)    
    while(!intersect_top){
      b_top <- b_top - step    
      a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*log(mx_tmp$time)
      intersect_top <- any(tmp$x > b_top*log(tmp$time) + a_top)    
    }  
    b_top <- b_top + step
    a_top <- mx_tmp$x - b_top*log(mx_tmp$time)
    while(!intersect_bot){
      b_bot <- b_bot + step    
      a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*log(mn_tmp$time) 
      intersect_bot <- any(tmp$x < b_bot*log(tmp$time) + a_bot)    
    }  
    b_bot <- b_bot - step
    a_bot <- mn_tmp$x - b_bot*log(mn_tmp$time)
  }
  return(list(bottom = list(a = a_bot, b=b_bot), 
              top = list(a = a_top, b=b_top), 
              log=log))
  
}
```

```r
f <- find_lines(x)
plot(x, type="l")
abline(f$top$a, f$top$b, col="red")
abline(f$bot$a, f$bot$b, col="red")
f <- find_lines(x, log=TRUE, step=1e-1)
lines(1:length(x), f$top$a + f$top$b*log(1:length(x)), col="green")
lines(1:length(x), f$bot$a + f$bot$b*log(1:length(x)), col="green")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, using `pracma::findpeaks` . Adjust the number `n` to get a "pleasing" curve of desired smoothness.

### however

All these answers depend heavily on which local extrema you want to "count" in your estimate of the bounding lines.  If you want, for example, a straight line which allows no peak to be above the line, then Gabor's approach may be what you want. That loses a lot of information about the "startup" behavior, and essentially assumes the data are converging to a steady-state value with no subsequent oscillations.

The code below in this answer tracks the data on the assumption that the high-frequency components decay faster than the low-frequency components but that you want to track those low-frequency components.

```
spx <- spline(x, n = 100)  
plot(x, pch = '.')
lines(spx, col='red', lwd = 2)
xhi <-findpeaks(spx$y)
points(spx$x[xhi[,2]], spx$y[xhi[,2]],col='green')
xlo <- findpeaks(-spx$y)
points(spx$x[xlo[,2]], spx$y[xlo[,2]],col='blue')
```

Then you can draw a fitting curve  to the green points and the blue points.

[image]